# Where is the logout/screenlock button/menu on a stock Ubuntu Unity 13.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, logout

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a new machine, admiring the clean spartan interface not cluttered with anything like an Applications or systems menu.  Apart from the dock-like thing to the left, it's absolutely zen-empty. This is the exact kind of interface I've long felt that Linux should adopt on the desktop if it was going to win the hearts and minds of people who never do any work.

But I have stuff to do.

I see how to launch apps, in particular a terminal window.

How do I logout?  And, which I do far more frequently, how do I lock the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Log in with the gnome-fallback theme
2. Run `gnome-panel` after logging in

I also turned off global menus, enabled workspace switching,
and my desktop is no longer acting like it's a 32" tablet.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can lock the screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. If you go to the upper right corner of the screen, the last icon on the right should produce a menu when clicked that contains items like `About This Computer`, `System Settings`, `Lock Screen`, `Log Out...`, `Restart`, `Shut Down`, etc.

Comment: I should have given more info.  I transfered all my files from an ubuntu 12.04 LTS equipped with the gnome classic settings to a new box running ubuntu 13.10.  Now all I have on the screen is the dock and my opened windows.  All there is in the upper part of the screen is the name of the active app in the upper-left. I know what that menu in the upper-right you're describing looks like, having used Linux since the Mandrake days. It's not there.